# NextAuth with HttpOnly cookies from external API

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Hi looking for a way to implement authentication and authorization with NextAuth and HttpOnly cookies from an external api.

So when you log in on the external api, you get the user info:

```
{
  id: '',
  email: '',
  role: ''
}
```

and you also get an Authentication and Refresh token on the `Set-Cookie` header (with a max-age of 300s and 1w, same expirations are used on the token).

So to my understanding, I have to do the following:

**In the authorize fn:**

- POST login, forward the `Set-Cookies` using `res.setHeader`
- read out Authentication token and get `exp` (expiration in seconds)
- return the accesTokenExp and the user data

**JWT Callback:**

- on signin (when user is defined), add user to the token object
- check if Date.now() is past accessToken expiry, if not return token else
- get new accessToken in `Set-Cookie` and UserModel from api and forward it using `res.setHeader`
- return token with user and new accesTokenExp

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { RestUserModel } from '../../../types/models';
import logger from '../../../utils/logger';
import { getData, postData } from '../../../utils/request';
import { getCookieValue, getTokenExpiryFromCookies } from '../../../utils/utils';
import jsonwebtoken from "jsonwebtoken"

type NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => NextAuthOptions

interface UserToken extends RestUserModel {
  accessTokenExpiry: number
}

const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): NextAuthOptions => {
  return {
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        name: "Credentials",
        credentials: {
          email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "jhon@doe.com" },
          password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" }
        },
        async authorize(credentials) {
          logger.info(`NextAuth authorize for user ${credentials?.email}`);

          try {
            const response = await postData<RestUserModel>('/auth/signin', {
              body: {
                email: credentials?.email,
                password: credentials?.password,
              },
            })

            logger.info("Authorization was successful!");

            const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'] || [];
            console.log(cookies)
            logger.info("cookies: " + cookies);
            res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies)

            const accessToken = getCookieValue(cookies.join(','), 'Authentication') || '';
            logger.info('token: ' + accessToken)
            logger.info('tokenSecret: ' + process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET)
            logger.info('cookie decoding: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonwebtoken.decode(accessToken), null, 2));
            const accessTokenExpiry = (getTokenExpiryFromCookies(cookies.join(',')) || 0) * 1000;

            return {
              ...response.data,
              accessTokenExpiry,
            }
          } catch (error: any) {
            logger.error(`NextAuth authorize error: ${error.message}`);
            throw new Error(error)
          }
        }
      })
    ],
    callbacks: {
      async signIn({ user }) {
        if (!(user.role === "admin" || user.role === "manager")) return false
        return true
      },
      async jwt({ token, user }) {
        logger.info(`JWT User ${JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}`);
        logger.info(`JWT Token ${JSON.stringify(token, null, 2)}`);

        if (user) {
          token.user = user
        }

        const shouldrefreshtime = Math.round(((token.user as UserToken).accessTokenExpiry - 60 * 1000) - Date.now())

        logger.info(`Token accessExpiry: ${(token.user as UserToken).accessTokenExpiry} - Date.now(): ${Date.now()}`)
        logger.info(`Token accessExpiry - 60ms * 1000: ${(token.user as UserToken).accessTokenExpiry - 60 * 1000}`)
        logger.info(`Token should refresh: ${shouldrefreshtime}`)
        if (shouldrefreshtime > 0) return token;

        try {
          const response = await getData<RestUserModel>('/auth/refresh', {
            cookies: 'Refresh=' + req.cookies['Refresh']
          })
          
          response.headers['set-cookie'] && res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', response.headers['set-cookie'])

          const accessTokenExpiry = getTokenExpiryFromCookies((response.headers['set-cookie'] || []).join(','));

          logger.debug(`JWT Refresh Response Cookies: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers['set-cookie'], null, 2)}`)
          
          delete token.error;

          return {
            ...token,
            user: {
              ...response.data,
              accessTokenExpiry: (accessTokenExpiry || 0) * 1000
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error(`JWT Callback ERROR: ${error}`)

          return {
            ...token,
            error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
          }
        }
      },
      async session({ session, user, token }) {
        console.log('session', { session, user, token })
        return {
          ...session,
          user: {
            ...session.user,
            ...token.user as UserToken,
          },
        }
      }
    },
    session: {
      strategy: "jwt"
    },
    events: {
      async signOut() {
        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", [
          "Authentication=deleted;Max-Age=0;path=/;",
          "Refresh=deleted;Max-Age=0;path=/;"
        ]);
      },
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  }
}

const Auth = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  return NextAuth(req, res, nextAuthOptions(req, res))
}

export default Auth;
```

There seem to be an issue with the Refresh cookie being undefined.

But now I wonder if there isn't an easier way. I seem to be doing twice the work. Also is the use of NextAuth a good solution for this external API?